# What will be the regex for replacing lowercase followed by period followed by uppercase?

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace an occurrence of a lowercase in a string followed by a period followed by an uppercase (without any space) to contain a space also.

For example:

```
...inconvenient.The...
```

gets converted to

```
...inconvenient. The...
```

What is an approach for this in Java, possibly using regex?

Comment: You should post some codes to show that you, at least, tried.

Comment: @pandeSai I don't have any idea about forming regular expressions. Will be learning it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to insert a space character after a *lowercase* and a *dot* if it's followed by an *uppercase*..

```
String s = "foo.Bar and bar.Baz but not FOO.BAR or BAR.baz";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z]\\.)(?=[A-Z])", " ");
System.out.println(s); //=> "foo. Bar and bar. Baz but not FOO.BAR or BAR.baz"
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=            # look behind to see if there is:
 [a-z]          # any character of: 'a' to 'z'
 \.             # '.'
)               # end of look-behind
(?=             # look ahead to see if there is:
 [A-Z]          # any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)               # end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

like this? `s/([a-z])\.([A-Z])/$1. $2/`

Comment: Given that the question is tagged Java, it's fairly likely that people won't understand this (Java doesn't use that syntax for specifying regex).

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
result = subject.replace(/([a-z]\.)([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(                        # group and capture to \1:
  [a-z]                  #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
  \.                     #   '.'
)                        # end of \1
(                        # group and capture to \2:
  [A-Z]                  #   any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)                        # end of \2
```